# Why altering of a column is not permitted through query but easily done is server explorer

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am having a question i.e when i tried to alter a data type of a table by query or by modifying the data type directly i used to get some errors stating this can not be done. But where as if i open the same table in `server explorer` from `visual studio` and modify the data type it was easily done with out any errors.

I tried to modify the `primary key` which is a `foreign key` for some tables from data type  `int` to `varchar` using `Management Studio` it throw me some errors.

But the same thing when i done through `Server explorer` from `Visual Studio` it was done in a fraction.

Can any one tell what was the difference

Comment: Post your data access code and the code where you're trying to modify the data.

Comment: I didn't write any code just I right click on the column and try to edit the data type from both ways, while in `sql management studio` i got errors but when i do the same in `server explorer` it was done with out any errors

Comment: +1, for a good question.

Comment: Did you tried my suggested approach, I'm curious if that was the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I had this issue (at least with sql server 2008):

- Take a look at `Tools->Options->Designers`.
- uncheck "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation"
  and try again.

You can see more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895146.aspx) about when it occurs if the option is checked.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your specific error, all I can say is that the UI does far more than a simple command. It sometimes creates temporary storage and the copies data as it needs to, to make the experience pleasant. You should use the scripting function in the UI to capture the change and see what it's doing?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using a query, because that's exactly what SQL Server does. However, the script is considerably more complex than a simple `ALTER TABLE` statement; generally involving creating a temporary table with the changed datatype, copying the data from the original table, dropping the original table, then renaming the temporary table.

When modifying the structure of a table in the Design view in SSMS there is an option to generate the script for the change(s), so you can run it on multiple servers, etc. This will show you the exact process that is actually happening behind the scenes.